# Existence of closed complement space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. Show that for any subspace $Y\subset X$ with $\dim(Y)<\infty$ there is a closed space $Z$ such that $Y\cap Z =\{0\}$ and $Y+Z=X$.

So my thoughts: I know that for any finite sequence of linearly independent $(x_i)\in Y\subseteq X$ such that $\operatorname{span}(x_i)=Y$ there is an $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x_i)=r_i\in \mathbb{R}$. So I thought that I must think of $Z=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ being the kernel of $f$, so each element of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ forms a basis of $Z=\operatorname{span}(X\setminus Y)$. So obviously $Z$ must be closed since $f$ is bounded and therefore continuous. But I still don't figure out how to prove the statement.

Comment: Start with an isomorphism $f\colon Y \to \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do I then have to make an induction by adding a vector to the kernel or what is the strategy?

Comment: No induction. Just apply Hahn-Banach a finite number of times.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hm I don't see how I should apply Hahn-Banach when I start with an isomorphism? Do I have to look at the geometrical version of Hahn-Banach i.e. the seperation by an hyperplane? Or do I have to apply Hahn-Banach to the function $f^{-1}$ on the subspace $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an isomorphism $f \colon Y \to \mathbb{C}^n$ (where $n = \dim Y$). Note that since $Y$ is finite-dimensional (and Hausdorff), $f$ is automatically continuous.

Now extend $f$ to a continuous linear map $F \colon X \to \mathbb{C}^n$ using the Hahn-Banach extension theorem (to each component function). Then $Z = \ker F$ is a closed subspace of $X$ (by continuity of $F$) with $Z\cap Y = \{0\}$ (since $f = F\lvert_Y$ is an isomorphism) and $X = Y + Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ a basis for $Y$ and let us denote, for $i=1,...,n$, the linear span of $B \setminus \{x_i\}$ by $Y_i$.

Then $Y_i$ is a closed subspace of $X$, since $ \dim Y_i=n-1$. Since $x_i \notin Y_i$, the Hahn-Banach theorem shows that there is $f_i \in X^*$ with

$f_i=0$ on $Y_i$ and $f_i(x_i)=1$.

Now define $P:X \to X$ by

$$Px= \sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)x_i.$$

It is easy to see that $P$ is a bounded linear operator on $X$ , $P^2=P$ and $P(X)=Y$. Since $Q:=I-P$ is also a bounded projection, $Q(X)$ is closed. Now verify that $Z:=Q(X)$ has the desired properties.